# Having more than more animation on one rig

Tags: animation, rigging, unity, dopesheet

On this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyI1zfvUjeM at 0:28 the guy starts to explain that he has 3 different animations as seen on the dopesheet. How can I have the animations cut into 3 different animations?

**EDIT:** I found a way to do what I want. No more help needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from dope sheet to action editor and add actions (animations).

[image]

Comment: But how do I create two different ones. I know how to create an animation but don't know how to... name them and group them up to be their own animation. I don't really know how to explain.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by add actions? How do I link the movement with the so called created "action"?